# PHP regexp removes empty BB-tags

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regexp, that removes BB-tags from string. But I need to remove only empty BB-tags. Can you modify my regular expression?

```
$message = preg_replace("#\[\/?[a-z0-9\*\+\-]+(?:=(?:".*"|[^\]]*))?(?::[a-z])?(\:$uid)\]#", '', $message);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't "#\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\[/\1\\]#" enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '[a]asd[/a] [b][/b][c][/c]';

var_dump(preg_replace('~\[([^\]]+)\]\[/\\1\]~', '', $str));
```